# hard coding a waypoint into the drone kit

Tags: java, android

I have this source code from drone kit and i am trying to hard code a specific coordinates for a specific location so that we the drone take off it will land at the same location. here is the code that I am linking with a button option that the user can click after the drone is armed and ready to go.

```
public void onBtnbringmymail(View view) {
    State vehicleState = this.drone.getAttribute(AttributeType.STATE);

    if (vehicleState.isFlying()) {
        // Land
        VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).setVehicleMode(VehicleMode.COPTER_LAND, new SimpleCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(int executionError) {
                alertUser("Unable to land the vehicle.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {
                alertUser("Unable to land the vehicle.");
            }
        });
    } else if (vehicleState.isArmed()) {
        // Take off
        ControlApi.getApi(this.drone).takeoff(10, new AbstractCommandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                alertUser("Taking off...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i) {
                alertUser("Unable to take off.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {
                alertUser("Unable to take off.");
            }
        });
    } else if (!vehicleState.isConnected()) {
        // Connect
        alertUser("Connect to a drone first");
    } else {
        // Connected but not Armed
        VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).arm(true, false, new SimpleCommandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(int executionError) {
                alertUser("Unable to arm vehicle.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeout() {
                alertUser("Arming operation timed out.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to add an if statement with coordinates functionality to be active when a user press a button from the UI to call the drone to go to a specific location which is already announced in above loop with a predefined coordinates?

Comment: if drone is armed, take off, fly to (lat, long) and land

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment, the steps to do would be like:

- On Button Press, perform ActionA
- ActionA consists of multiple sub actions
  ** Check if armed
- - Take Off
- - Check current coordinates and validate against target coordinates
- - - If equals, then land
- - - If unequals, calculate vector and follow that vector

In pseudo code, it would look like this:

```
public class Autopilot
{

    // To be called by a button press
    public void execute()
    {
        if(systems.isEngaged() AND systems.isLanded())
        {
            takeOff();
        }
    }

    public void takeOff()
    {
        // Execute TakeOff procedures

        validateFlightPath();
    }

    public void validateFlightPath()
    {

        // Not within some meters to the target.
        while(!systems.getGps().getCurrentCoordinates().withinRange(targetCoordinates, coordinateThreshold)
        {         
            flyTo(targetCoordinates);
        }

        land();
    }

    public void flyTo(Coordinates coords)
    {
        Coordinates currentCoords = system.getGps().getCurrentCoordinates();

        Vector3 flightVector = coords - currentCoords;
        system.getFlightControls()... // Setup your flight controls to  follow the flightVector;
    }

    public void land()
    {
        // Perform landing procedures
    }
}
```